# How to test for two or more exceptions in ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am using ScalaTest for unit testing. I currently have the following:

```
f(x) should produce[Exception]
```

I would like to specify two or more subclasses of Exception, e.g.

```
f(x) should (produce[ExceptionA] or produce[ExceptionB])
```

Is this possible? If not, what is the recommended way to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at restructuring either your code or your tests if you've got a block of code that is non-deterministic in the exception that it will throw. That said, you could use an `evaluating` block to capture the thrown exception and then check if it's one of the required types. e.g.

```
val caught = evaluating {
  // code that should throw an exception
} should produce [Exception]
```

then

```
assert(caught.isInstanceOf[ExceptionA] || caught.isInstanceOf[ExceptionB])
```